# Powershell command to Update the NOTES field of a Cloud DL

Tags: azure, powershell

How can I update the NOTES field of a DL ( Exchange Distribution List) in the (O365) CLOUD. The DL was originally created on-prem and was synced to the Cloud (via Azure). 
Since the DL was created on-prem i cannot modify it in the cloud.
With this command:

```
Set-Group –identity "DLNAME" –Notes “Test Notes”
```

I get an error:
The action 'Set-Group', 'Notes', can't be performed on the object because the object is being synchronized from your on-premises organization.

Hence I was going through https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-edit-a-distribution-group-note-field-in-the/16dfe5c7-d4fb-464b-b3f2-36591016c560. So is it possible to run a powershell command in azure to update the Notes FIELD there? Or any other powershell command that will get the DL notes to show up in the cloud too.
Thanks

Comment: You need to be [assigned permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/find-exchange-cmdlet-permissions?view=exchange-ps) before you can run this cmdlet. And distribution group owners must manage the group by using on-premises tools for Exchange Server. Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/distribution-groups/cannot-manage-dg).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not feasible, **`Distribution groups`** that are created in Office 365 through directory synchronization must be managed in the on-premises environment.

Distribution group owners must manage the group by using on-premises tools for Exchange Server such as the following:

- Exchange Admin Center
- Exchange Management Console
- Exchange Management Shell

After changes are made to the group in the on-premises environment, the changes are synced to Office 365 the next time that directory synchronization runs.

Check this link [for additional reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/distribution-groups/cannot-manage-dg). Hope it helps.

Comment: Mohit, I already mentioned in my question that the DL was created on-prem. Maybe I did not clarify that we are already aware that the change if any had to be done on-prem. But then again, the NOTE already exists for the DL on-prem but not for the DL in the cloud. So there is nothing to update on the on-prem side for the DL.